# Prevent two-column list from page breaking

Tags: lists, page-breaking, enumerate, two-column, multicolumn

I am using `multicols` in an `enumerate` environment to split the list into two columns. Toward the end of a page, LaTeX breaks the list across pages, which changes the order in which the list items are displayed. I tried using `samepage` to keep I have an enumerate environment from being split across pages:

```
\begin{samepage}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $Top left$
\item $Middle left$
\item $Bottom left$
\item $Top right$
\item $Middle right$
\item $Bottom right$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{samepage}
```

However, then `multicols` stops working and the entire list is displayed in one column instead of two columns. Apparently `samepage` and `multicols` are incompatible with each other. I tried using `minipage` instead of `samepage`, and that resulted in a compilation error. Is there another way to prevent a two-column list from being broken across pages?

Thanks!

Comment: minipage is what you want here

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle . Using `minipage` instead of `samepage` gives a compilation error.

Comment: not if you use it correctly but you have not provided any real example that can be run to see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You just need to use a minipage to keep the list together:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
A two column itemize:
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $Top left$
\item $Middle left$
\item $Bottom left$
\item $Top right$
\item $Middle right$
\item $Bottom right$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
zzz
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! I think the reason `minipage` wasn't working for me before is I had omitted the `{\textwidth}` specification. Works wonderfully now. I appreciate your help!